# Java Tree data structure

Tags: java, tree

when we do node.getChildCount() , where node is the one of tree node ,in that case the method will only return the child count , but it will not consider the child's child (e.g.- grand child) ...so is there any predefined method,  for get the child as well as grandchild count....?? or any other way to get the count?

Comment: Do you want to use Java or Javascript? Although the names are very similar, in fact there are big differences between each other.

Comment: some understandable English would help understanding your question ...

Comment: Java only...        +a                 
   |----+b                           
   |    |----d                        
   |    |----e               
   |----+c                         
   |    |----f   (eg. if here we do a.getChildCount(), it will give 3 ... but I want to count all the child and the grandchild count ..so expected would be 6...

Comment: why wouldn't overriding DefaultMutableNode's getChildCount() mehtod to recursively call childrens getChildCount() work?

Answer (score 0):

```
Enumeration e = node.depthFirstEnumeration();
int count = 0;
while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
    count++;
    e.nextElement();
}
```

count now holds number of nodes of the subtree rooted at node.
You might want to subtract 1.

Comment: @Buhb.. thnx for the depthFirstEnumeration suggestion with some modification and type casting it works...!!